# What's meaning of this ocaml code segment?

Tags: ocaml

I can't understand this ocaml code from ocaml compiler source code:

```
File: d:\src\ocaml-4.07.0\driver\pparse.ml
50: type 'a ast_kind =
51: | Structure : Parsetree.structure ast_kind
52: | Signature : Parsetree.signature ast_kind
```

there define a type ast_kind,define the type parameter 'a,but not use it?

I know the common use of type define like this:

```
type a=
|A of int
|B of int
```

so the

```
Structure : Parsetree.structure ast_kind
```

means what?the type of Structure is Parsetree.structure? or ast_kind?

I read the offical doc:
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-312/manual016.html#@manual.kwd53

it tell me only in the defination of record can use the ":"

```
type-representation ::= = constr-decl  { | constr-decl }   
                     ∣  = { field-decl  { ; field-decl } }

field-decl ::= field-name :  poly-typexpr   
           ∣  mutable field-name :  poly-typexpr
```

so what's the meaning of this code segment?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from :

```
    50: type 'a ast_kind =
    51: | Structure : Parsetree.structure ast_kind
    52: | Signature : Parsetree.signature ast_kind
```

This is read as follows :

line 50 : we define a parametrized type `ast_kind` whose parameter is `'a`. The parameter is defined later in the lines 51 & 52.
On line 51 : the `'a` parameter type is `Parsetree.structure`
And similarly for line 52.

Now, more generally, `ast_kind` is a GADT type (generalized algebraic datatypes), see [GADT-manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#s%3Agadts) and another example : [Mads-hartmann](https://mads-hartmann.com/ocaml/2015/01/05/gadt-ocaml.html).

Note that GADT has been introduced in Ocaml 4.00 - so the link you quote regarding documentation is outdated for that particular feature as it refers to Ocaml 3.12. You are currently inspecting the source code of Ocaml 4.07.